# Ordenar un Treeview en Tkinter haciendo clic en los headings de las columnas

Tags: python, tkinter

buenas tardes;

Estoy armando una base para ingresar reclamos y quisiera ordenar los datos que se muestran en el TreeView según el heading sobre el que se haga clic. Por ejemplo, al hacer clic sobre "ID", quisiera que se ordene de menor a mayor y viceversa al hacer clic nuevamente.
No tengo código para compartirles porque no tengo idea cómo escribir la función.

Desde ya muchas gracias por lo que me puedan comentar.

Saludos!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

El widget `Treeview` no ofrece esta funcionalidad, pero no es complicado implementarla. La idea básica se apoya en dos puntos:

- Usar el argumento `command` del método  `Tree.heading` para llamar a una *callback* cada vez que el usuario hace click en el *header* de la columna.
- En la *callback* obtenemos todas las parejas (indice, valor) de la columna y las ordenamos en función del valor. Para ello podemos usar el *built-in* `sorted`. Hecho esto basta con usar `Tree.move` para mover cada item a su nueva posición según su indice en la lista ordenada obtenida.

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import functools
import operator
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        columns = ('nombre', 'apellido', 'edad')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=columns, show='headings')

        self.tree.heading(
            'nombre',
            text='Nombre',
            command=functools.partial(self.sort_by_column, 'nombre')
            )
        self.tree.heading(
            'apellido',
            text='Apellido',
            command=functools.partial(self.sort_by_column, 'apellido')
            )
        self.tree.heading(
            'edad',
            text='Edad',
            command=functools.partial(self.sort_by_column, 'edad')
            )

        self.tree.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        rows = [("Maria", "Castaño", 25),
                ("Antonio", "Garcia", 34),
                ("Laura", "Lopez", 17),
                ("Javier", "Ruiz", 42)]

        for row in rows:
            self.tree.insert('', tk.END, values=row)

    def sort_by_column(self, column_name, reverse=False):
        column_index = self.tree["columns"].index(column_name)
        sorted_items = sorted(
            ((self.tree.item(item)["values"][column_index], item)
             for item in self.tree.get_children()),
            key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=reverse)

        for index, (_, item) in enumerate(sorted_items):
            self.tree.move(item, '', index)

        self.tree.heading(
            column_name,
            command=functools.partial(
                self.sort_by_column, column_name, not reverse
                )
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('620x200')
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]